# DNS server setting resets on reboot

Tags: mac, networking, osx-snow-leopard

I recently changed my physical location, and had to change my DNS server setting in network preferences. However my Mac reverts back to original DNS server IP address on each reboot and I have to manually change it everytime. How can I make my changes persist on reboot?

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.7

### **UPDATE**

This is has started to occur since the time I restored my entire system from TM backup.

Comment: What method did you use to change them in the first place?

Comment: always used network preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Does the preferred DNS Server show up in Advanced... → DNS → DNS Servers list?

First, try to [repair your hard disk permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963).

If that doesn't help, try deleting the network interface and add it again (minus and plus buttons in Network Preferences).

Answer (score 0):

Check your DHCP server settings. It sounds like they are updating them every time.